# Configure React-Native To Run Lint On Code Updates (Expo/Metro/Webpack/Watchman)

Tags: react-native, expo, eslint, watchman

In ember.js, there is a neat feature that on every code update, the server (or something-- I'm not sure) lints the files changed and outputs it before rebuilding the code (note, in more recent versions of ember, [you need to add a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64545941/from-ember-serve-how-to-run-lint-on-each-new-build)).

I really like this feature, and want to implement it in my react-native app.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any way or documentation on how to do this or how the linter works in ember.

I know that some IDEs have lint highlighting, but I don't want to become reliant or force people to use IDEs, and it would just be a nice quality of life improvement instead of having to run lint tests manually.

I'm running react-native in Expo latest version managed workflow.

Does anyone know how to configure things to run lint automatically on code updates?  Is it a Watchman config?  Metro config?  Webpack?  Expo?  Something else entirely?